# alignment issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, sidebar

Here is my bootstrap html code

```
 <div class="span3">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          
          <li class="nav-header">Practice</li>
          <li align="right"><a href="#" onclick='Show();'>None</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick='Show();'>All</a></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;ABC</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;LPO</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;MNJ</li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vG8tW/1/)

How to get the `None | All` aligned in a single line and how to make the checkbox and the corresponding text also aligned in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the unnecessary code for clarification purposes.

First of all, use two lists:

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-header">Practice</li>
    <li align="right"><a href="#" onclick='Show();'>None</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick='Show();'>All</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;ABC</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;LPO</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;MNJ</li>
</ul>
```

Then use that CSS:

```
ul li { display: inline; }
```

To align the checkboxes with their text, add this to your CSS

```
ul li input { position: relative; top: -3px; }
```

Adjust the `top` attribute to what best fits on your page.

Comment: by aligning check box and text i meant ....in first line one check box and corresponding text, den in next line the other.Its already that way in my code but if u noticed the text is a little above the checkbox

Comment: Ok, I've edited it with the alignment for the checkboxes. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/vG8tW/5/

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your structure, here's the css that will fix your problem,

```
div{
  float: left;
}
li{
  float: left;
    clear: left;
}
li > a{
  float: left;
}
li > a:last-child{
 float: right;
}
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vG8tW/4/)

**UPDATE:**

You'll need to wrap your text with `<span>`, so your html will look like so,

```
<li ><input type="checkbox"/><span>ABC</span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"/><span>LPO</span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"/><span>MNJ</span></li>
```

And the css,

```
li > span{
    float: right;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/vG8tW/9/)

Comment: check box and corresponding text not aligned

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

for None | All

and for check-box use

```
<li><input type="checkbox">&nbsp;ABC
<input type="checkbox">&nbsp;LPO
<input type="checkbox">&nbsp;MNJ</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
.nav-list > li[align="right"] > a{
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
}
.nav-list > li input{
   vertical-align:top; 
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/vG8tW/6/

Answer (score -1):

Use following code

```
          <li class="nav-header">Practice</li>
          <li align="right">
              <a href="#" style="float:left;margin-left:70px;"  onclick='Show();'>None</a>
              &nbsp;|&nbsp;
              <a href="#"   style="float:right;" onclick='Show();'>All</a>
            </li>
            <div style="clear:both;">
          <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;ABC</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;LPO</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;MNJ</li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
```

Comment: You're using inline css and solving it with float, when all that's needed is to define the inner content of the lists as inline. You're also using DIV inside a list.

Answer (score -1):

Add following styles

```
.nav > li{
display:inline;
}
.nav > li.nav-header,.nav > li[align]{
 display:block;   
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vG8tW/8/)